# Paperclip migration not accepting in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a cook book that users can attach images with using paperclip. I was able to generate a paperclip cookbook image, but when i try to `rake db:migrate` it gives me this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: cookbooks: ALTER TABLE "cookbooks" ADD "image_file_name" varchar(255)/Users/WhiteMacbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Would this involve me going in to the terminal and adding the column to the cookbooks table myself?

Any help is apperciated! Thank you

EDIT! Here is my schema, I do have a cookbooks table;

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140811235307) do

  create_table "cook_books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

EDIT! I changed the table names from cookbook to cook_book, ran rake db: and got this;

```
== 20140812175524 AddAttachmentImageToCookbooks: migrating ====================
-- change_table(:cook_books)
   -> 0.0056s
== 20140812175524 AddAttachmentImageToCookbooks: migrated (0.0057s) ===========
```

Comment: According to this error, there is no table `cookbooks`, can we see your `schema.rb`?

Comment: It tells you the table cookbooks doesn't exist. Did you make sure have a create_table cookbooks in your previous migrations?

Comment: Ah, it's because your table name has an underscore in it. I generally would suggest against that. Make sure all references to that table are `cook_books` and not `cookbooks` if you want to leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `schema` table called `cook_books`, and the error says there is no table called `cookbooks`. SO change the name in either place (so that the table name and call to it are equal) and you will be good to go.

Comment: so how would I go about that? I assume I can leave the table in the schema, but my model is 'CookBook'

Comment: Okay, so I added underscores to my add_attachments_to_cookbook migration and the rake:db did this;